# Delete infinite nested directories

Tags: bash, directory, nested, infinite

I found out on one of my servers an infinite succession of empty sub-directories.
I tried :

```
rm -Rf <dir>
```

Then

```
find . -name /<dir>/* -exec rm -f {} \;
```

And eventually

```
rsync -a --delete /emptydir/* /<dir>/*
```

But none of these worked out.
Does anyone have a better idea?

Thanks a lot.

PS : just so you know, I tried a "find" command with "mindepth" argument and I still have something after 8000 subdirs...

Comment: should be `rm -rf  DIR `, not capital R

Comment: @BMW both, `-r` and `-R` are allowed and mean the same

Comment: @otanein, what's the output, afte run the rm -Rf ?

Comment: Think the `rm -rf ` shall be enough to remove the folders, of course if your filesystem is valid, if you can't do `rm -rf`, at first check fs in lost chains, and other disasters: `/sbin/fsck /dev/sda1` or similar.

Comment: @BMV actually, the command hangs and nothing more happens

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ what do you mean by valid? sane?

Comment: valid mean intact, holistic.

Answer (score 1):

There can't be an indefinite loop of sub dirs if you ignore symlinks. I guess you are a victim of symlinks.

Therefore use the following command, it will only find directories not symlinks:

```
find -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Wait until it is ready. You can see if it really hangs using `strace`. I don't believe that, or at least I don't expect `find` being the issue

Answer (score 0):

You might want to delete directories depth-first:

```
find . -depth -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

`find` doesn't follow symbolic links by default.